# About a Dirichlet series

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I would like to know if the following assertion is true:
Let consider a real decreasing sequence $(t_n)$ of positive numbers with limit zero, if the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(t_n)^a$ is divergent for all real $a$ in $[0,1[$ then the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty t_n$ is also divergent?
thanks in advance

Comment: For some basic information about typing mathematical expressions on Stack Exchange sites, see: [How does one type mathematical formulas on this site?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3763) To help you get started, I have edited your post - I hope this is at least approximately close to what you intended, but if not please edit your post further. It was a bit unclear whether you want to ask about *sequence* or about *series* - in case it helps you, you can write sum as `\sum` $\sum$ or `\sum_{n=1}^\infty` $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$. (To get math rendered, it has to be included between dollar signs.)

Comment: I mean " the series \sum  tn^a is divergent for all a in [0,1[ , does it follow that the series \sum tn is also divergent"; thanks for your help

Comment: BTW I'd guess that ([tag:ca.classical-analysis-and-odes]) would be a more suitable [top-level tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/frequently-asked-questions-about-tagging-on-mathoverflow#1076) than ([tag:nt.number-theory]). But probably it's better if I leave this up to you - I do not want to go overboard with editing your question.

Comment: This isn't a Dirichlet series.

Answer (score 5):

What about $t_n=\frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}$?

Comment: thanks a lot; i tried 2  days to prove it (without success), now i know more:its false